# list of math intense graduate level microeconomics books?

Tags: microeconomics, mathematical-economics, reference-request

List of math intense graduate level microeconomics books?

Except Reny's book, krep's books, varian's book and mas-collell's book

books from subfields are acceptable, however by math intense i mean most of the books pages contain some level of math

Please categorize the book

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For game theory:

*[Game Theory](https://mitpress.mit.edu/index.php?q=books/game-theory)* by Fudenberg and Tirole

*[Repeated Games and Reputations : Long-Run Relationships](https://books.google.ca/books?id=jhEU8f6J0IQC&dq=mailath%20samuelson%20repeated%20games%20and%20reputations&source=gbs_navlinks_s)* by Mailath and Samuelson

*[The Theory of Learning in Games](https://mitpress.mit.edu/index.php?q=books/theory-learning-games)* by Fudenberg and Levine

*[Evolutionary Game Theory](https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/evolutionary-game-theory)* by Weibull

Answer (score 7):

[Mas-Collel](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0195073401) is very popular. It is very math-heavy. Every idea and concept is done pretty rigorously and it pretty well covers everything. The book is a very slow read and is sometimes uneven. Very detailed in some sections and not as good in others. That said, in my experience, it is the **graduate microeconomics** bible. If you have a question, your answer is somewhere in there.

Answer (score 3):

For stochastic processes and calc, Dixit's *The Art of Smooth Pasting* is written for the econ audience.

Answer (score 2):

Myerson is pretty well-structured in his math: [Game Theory](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0674341163)

Answer (score 2):

There is also

Felix Muñoz-Garcia: advanced microeconomic theory
(this comes with a book of solved practice questions)

and

Silberberg: The structure of economics
(old but written so well where much the needed math is explained along with the economics)

For consumer choice - no firm theory - the book by

Deaton and Muellbauer: Economics and consumer behavior

is also a really nice book.